# Find all column names containing a string and converting the contents of the columns

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I was wondering how I could find all columns that contain 'Date' and change them to date time. The code below can change a column to date time but only one at a time.

I was wondering how I could find all columns with the string 'Date' in them and change each column to datetime.

```
#data.DATE_cols = pd.to_datetime(data.Date_cols)
```

this code creates a df with two date columns and just lists them.
how could I convert each column to datetime instead of just listing them?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ['bob','sam','jim'], 'DateOpen': ['1/1/2010','1-1-2010','1/1/2010'], 'DateClose': ['1/1/2010','1-1-2010','1/1/2010'], 'no': [10,11,12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Date_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'Date' in col]
print(list(df.columns))
print(Date_cols)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) in conjunction with the [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method

```
In [155]: df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('Date')] = \
              df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('Date')].apply(pd.to_datetime)

In [156]: df
Out[156]:
   DateClose   DateOpen Name  no
0 2010-01-01 2010-01-01  bob  10
1 2010-01-01 2010-01-01  sam  11
2 2010-01-01 2010-01-01  jim  12

In [157]: df.dtypes
Out[157]:
DateClose    datetime64[ns]
DateOpen     datetime64[ns]
Name                 object
no                    int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Awesome! thanks! it is telling my my year is out of range on one of my files though. for some reason it has some dates '0000-00-00' which I believe is causing the problem. But that is unrelated to my question. THANKS

Comment: @brandog, glad i could help :-)